# Why do we need URL.createObjectURL?

Tags: javascript

This is the code fro MDN showing createObjectURL example:

```
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(files[i]);
  img.height = 60;
  img.onload = function(e) {
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
  }
  li.appendChild(img);
```

The full document is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Using_object_URLs_to_display_images). Here is the [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.createObjectURL) for createObjectURL.

You can just pass a File object instead of the ObjectURL. My question is:

1. Why do they need a createObjectURL?
2. Why they name it xxxURL? Is it related to URL like "www.google.com?p=32&t=33"?

I have trouble understanding this thing. Let me know your thoughts. Thank you!

Comment: Its use to convert your Object to URL means blob object to blob URL

Comment: Is it possible? Object is a {a:3, b:4}, but a url is like www.google.com. Are you talking about encode an object to URL format?

Comment: I am talking about Blob object tell me now {a:3,b:4} is blob